# scan text (optical character recognition)

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

Is it possible to develop an app for windows mobile 6.5 that can scan/read text (Optical Character Recognition)?
Or if there was an app that existed like that?
I am about to develop an app that would require that function, and not being familiar to windows mobile i really dont know if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

there are some solutions out there. As windows mobile only has limitted resources, some solutions are using a server to upload an image and get back a text file.

The other solutions run on the device only. I did some tests with Abby Finereader SDK for Windows CE (they offer a PC test app to do so). But the resulty were not satisffying. The color cameras in windows mobile devices (tested up to 5MP) were to bad.

Intermec offer eMDI (enhanced Mobile Document Imaging) on some of there newer ruggedized handheld devices. This special imaging auto-corrects lightning and perspective of document pictures when taken with the software.This is a great solution to file documents up to A4 paper size.

Another working solution is an address label reading software called VERDEX. The software takes images (camera) of address labels, does an OCR on it and verifies the address against a database. If the address is not found, it represents you the OCR result of the label.

~josef